# Gráfico multi-line en amChart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Estimados, tengo el siguiente problema:

Como salida tengo un archivo `JSON` complejo y mediante la función `nested` de `d3` genero el siguiente `Array` para que me permita generar una gráfica `multiLine` en `amChart`:

```
var graph = [
    {"key": "2015-01-01", "value": {"pv": 100, "ev": 200, "ac": 200}},
    {"key": "2015-01-02", "value": {"pv": 300, "ev": 500, "ac": 400}},
    {"key": "2015-01-03", "value": {"pv": 600, "ev": 900, "ac": 700}},
    {"key": "2015-01-04", "value": {"pv": 800, "ev": 1000, "ac": 1500}},
    {"key": "2015-01-05", "value": {"pv": 1000, "ev": 1000, "ac": 1000}},
    {"key": "2015-01-06", "value": {"pv": 1700, "ev": 1300, "ac": 1200}},
    {"key": "2015-01-07", "value": {"pv": 2300, "ev": 2000, "ac": 2500}},
    {"key": "2015-01-08", "value": {"pv": 3100, "ev": 2300, "ac": 3200}},
    {"key": "2015-01-09", "value": {"pv": 3800, "ev": 2600, "ac": 3500}},
    {"key": "2015-01-10", "value": {"pv": 4200, "ev": 3500, "ac": 4000}}
];
```

y el código para generar la gráfica es el siguiente:

```js
var chart;

var graph = [
     {"key": "2015-01-01", "value": {"pv": 100, "ev": 200, "ac": 200}},
     {"key": "2015-01-02", "value": {"pv": 300, "ev": 500, "ac": 400}},
     {"key": "2015-01-03", "value": {"pv": 600, "ev": 900, "ac": 700}},
     {"key": "2015-01-04", "value": {"pv": 800, "ev": 1000, "ac": 1500}},
     {"key": "2015-01-05", "value": {"pv": 1000, "ev": 1000, "ac": 1000}},
     {"key": "2015-01-06", "value": {"pv": 1700, "ev": 1300, "ac": 1200}},
     {"key": "2015-01-07", "value": {"pv": 2300, "ev": 2000, "ac": 2500}},
     {"key": "2015-01-08", "value": {"pv": 3100, "ev": 2300, "ac": 3200}},
     {"key": "2015-01-09", "value": {"pv": 3800, "ev": 2600, "ac": 3500}},
     {"key": "2015-01-10", "value": {"pv": 4200, "ev": 3500, "ac": 4000}}
];      

AmCharts.ready(function () {
     // XY CHART

     chart = new AmCharts.AmXYChart();
     chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

     chart.dataProvider = graph;
     chart.startDuration = 1;

     // AXES
     // X
     var xAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
     xAxis.title = "X Axis";
     xAxis.position = "bottom";
     xAxis.dashLength = 1;
     xAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
     xAxis.type = "date";
     xAxis.autoGridCount = true;
     chart.addValueAxis(xAxis);

     // Y
     var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
     yAxis.position = "left";
     yAxis.title = "Y Axis";
     yAxis.dashLength = 1;
     yAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
     yAxis.autoGridCount = true;
     chart.addValueAxis(yAxis);

     // GRAPHS
     // triangles up
     var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
     graph1.lineColor = "#FF6600";
     graph1.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
     graph1.xField = "key";
     graph1.yField = "value.pv";
     graph1.lineAlpha = 1;
     graph1.type = "smoothedLine";
     graph1.bullet = "triangleUp";
     chart.addGraph(graph1);

     // triangles down
     var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
     graph2.lineColor = "#FCD202";
     graph2.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
     graph2.xField = "key";
     graph2.yField = "value.ac";
     graph2.lineAlpha = 1;
     graph2.type = "smoothedLine";
     graph2.bullet = "triangleDown";
     chart.addGraph(graph2);

     // triangles down
     var graph3 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
     graph3.lineColor = "#004B8D";
     graph3.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
     graph3.xField = "key";
     graph3.yField = "value.ev";
     graph3.lineAlpha = 1;
     graph3.type = "smoothedLine";
     graph3.bullet = "triangleDown";
     chart.addGraph(graph3);

     // primer trend line
     var trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
     trendLine.lineColor = "#FF6600";
     trendLine.initialXValue = 1;
     trendLine.initialValue = 2;
     trendLine.finalXValue = 12;
     trendLine.finalValue = 11;
     chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

     // segundo trend line
     trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
     trendLine.lineColor = "#FCD202";
     trendLine.initialXValue = 1;
     trendLine.initialValue = 1;
     trendLine.finalXValue = 12;
     trendLine.finalValue = 19;
     chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

     // tercer trend line
     trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
     trendLine.lineColor = "#004B8D";
     trendLine.initialXValue = 1;
     trendLine.initialValue = 1;
     trendLine.finalXValue = 12;
     trendLine.finalValue = 19;
     chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

     // CURSOR
     var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
     chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

     // SCROLLBAR
     var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
     chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

     // WRITE
     chart.write("chartEVM");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Multi Line con AMCharts</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3v4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="chartEVM" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EL problema es que se dibuja el eje de las fechas, pero no se dibujan los valores de `pv`, `ac` y `ev`.

Desde ya, agradezco a los que invierten su tiempo en ayudarme con este tema

> PD: Utilizo las funciones de `d3.js` para generar los `Arrays` porque soy nuevo en `JavaScript` y además porque creo que tiene muchas funciones que ahorran mucho tiempo en generar set de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Solamente elimina el objeto `value` y sitúa las propiedades directamente en cada objeto del `Array`:

```js
var chart;

var graph = [
     {"key": "2015-01-01", "pv": 100, "ev": 200, "ac": 200},
     {"key": "2015-01-02", "pv": 300, "ev": 500, "ac": 400},
     {"key": "2015-01-03", "pv": 600, "ev": 900, "ac": 700},
     {"key": "2015-01-04", "pv": 800, "ev": 1000, "ac": 1500},
     {"key": "2015-01-05", "pv": 1000, "ev": 1000, "ac": 1000},
     {"key": "2015-01-06", "pv": 1700, "ev": 1300, "ac": 1200},
     {"key": "2015-01-07", "pv": 2300, "ev": 2000, "ac": 2500},
     {"key": "2015-01-08", "pv": 3100, "ev": 2300, "ac": 3200},
     {"key": "2015-01-09", "pv": 3800, "ev": 2600, "ac": 3500},
     {"key": "2015-01-10", "pv": 4200, "ev": 3500, "ac": 4000}
];      

AmCharts.ready(function () {
     // XY CHART

     chart = new AmCharts.AmXYChart();
     chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

     chart.dataProvider = graph;
     chart.startDuration = 1;

     // AXES
     // X
     var xAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
     xAxis.title = "X Axis";
     xAxis.position = "bottom";
     xAxis.dashLength = 1;
     xAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
     xAxis.type = "date";
     xAxis.autoGridCount = true;
     chart.addValueAxis(xAxis);

     // Y
     var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
     yAxis.position = "left";
     yAxis.title = "Y Axis";
     yAxis.dashLength = 1;
     yAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
     yAxis.autoGridCount = true;
     chart.addValueAxis(yAxis);

     // GRAPHS
     // triangles up
     var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
     graph1.lineColor = "#FF6600";
     graph1.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
     graph1.xField = "key";
     graph1.yField = "pv";
     graph1.lineAlpha = 1;
     graph1.type = "smoothedLine";
     graph1.bullet = "triangleUp";
     chart.addGraph(graph1);

     // triangles down
     var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
     graph2.lineColor = "#FCD202";
     graph2.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
     graph2.xField = "key";
     graph2.yField = "ac";
     graph2.lineAlpha = 1;
     graph2.type = "smoothedLine";
     graph2.bullet = "triangleDown";
     chart.addGraph(graph2);

     // triangles down
     var graph3 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
     graph3.lineColor = "#004B8D";
     graph3.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
     graph3.xField = "key";
     graph3.yField = "ev";
     graph3.lineAlpha = 1;
     graph3.type = "smoothedLine";
     graph3.bullet = "triangleDown";
     chart.addGraph(graph3);

     // primer trend line
     var trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
     trendLine.lineColor = "#FF6600";
     trendLine.initialXValue = 1;
     trendLine.initialValue = 2;
     trendLine.finalXValue = 12;
     trendLine.finalValue = 11;
     chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

     // segundo trend line
     trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
     trendLine.lineColor = "#FCD202";
     trendLine.initialXValue = 1;
     trendLine.initialValue = 1;
     trendLine.finalXValue = 12;
     trendLine.finalValue = 19;
     chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

     // tercer trend line
     trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
     trendLine.lineColor = "#004B8D";
     trendLine.initialXValue = 1;
     trendLine.initialValue = 1;
     trendLine.finalXValue = 12;
     trendLine.finalValue = 19;
     chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

     // CURSOR
     var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
     chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

     // SCROLLBAR
     var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
     chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

     // WRITE
     chart.write("chartEVM");
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script> 
<div id="chartEVM" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
```